# How to achieve kudos app in sharepoint on premise

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to create a kudos app like this : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/10/31/building-a-cloud-business-app-kudos/#comment-17695

I have on premise SharePoint 2013 server. people who get kudos from someone should display with image and name. Please suggest.